# I will wondering if there is a difference between file = open('hello.txt','w') and file = open('hello.txt','wf') becase both are working

Tags: python-3.x

file = open('hello.txt','w')
file = open('hello.txt','wt')

"Both of these line create a file hello.txt. Are these line handle differently in the background?"

Comment: "w" and "wt" both have the same meaning, since you open the file in writing mode, by default, it is open in text writing mode which is the same as "wt".

Answer (score 0):

when use of w mean write but when use of wf means w+f and open for w and open for f in time

Comment: Thank you guys - much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you `open` a file with python, you can also define the `mode`. By default, the `mode` is `mode=r`, which means read.

When you use `mode=w`, you open the file for writing, truncating the file first.
When you use `mode=t`, you specify that you open it for text mode, this is also the default setting, like `mode=r`. You could also open it in binary with `mode=b`

So there is no difference between `mode=w` and `mode=wt`, as the `t` is by default used unless you state you want to open it in binary mode.

Read more about the different mode values in the official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)